# J2ME App Selectively Working on Some Phones

Tags: java, encryption, java-me, des

I'm currently working on a j2me app. The app encrypts(using DES) and sends username and password to a server which then decrypts and authenticates the supplied credentials. Tested it on a Nokia E63 and it worked well, but failed to work on some other phones that I tested it on like Bold 5 and LG C199. I tried debugging and found out that the program fails at the point where it instantiates the class responsible for the encryption.
Does anyone know how I can work around this? Also is there anyway I can write a DES encryption without using the javax.crypto.Cipher class?

Comment: Is javax.crypto.Cipher a part of the JME? I didn't think so.

Comment: It isn't. I didn't say it was a part of the J2ME. I just asked if there was a way to write a DES encryption algorithm that doesn't import from javax.crypto.Cipher.

Answer (score 0):

some of those phone's jvm might won't have that class, try adding that class explicitly in your application

Answer (score 0):

The [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) lightweight crypto API comes in a [j2me version](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/lcrypto-j2me-148.zip). Be sure to read the FAQ about running an obfuscator on your j2me thingy (I don't know squat about j2me so you'll have to fill in the blanks).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the j2me app working by replacing the standard java crypto encryption class with the bountycastle lightweight crypto api. That solved my problem.